# Postgres-update char column for spesifc string

Tags: database, postgresql

i have something that almost challenging to me that i want to update a column values based on condition.

I have a table called customers that contain the customer name and phone,i have a lot of records on it almost 40K record.
The phone numbers column is char and the records is like this `'100445216324.0'` but i want to update all the number that in the same way to: `0100445216324` ,,what i did here that i remove the `'.0'` in the last of the number and i add 0 in font of it.

How could i do this to all records in one simple update statement .
thanks

Comment: Is it always 0? if not, is it always 1 char after the dot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE my_table
SET tel = '0' || left(tel, -2)
WHERE right(tel, 2) = '.0';
```

This only updates telephone numbers that end in '.0'.

Comment: Will work only incase it always ends with only 1 number after the dot.

Comment: @sagi Which is just what the OP demonstrated.

Comment: I know, but that doesn't means it what he needs:)

Comment: there are a numbers end with '.0' and numbers not ,,, so you must add condition to check the phone number first

Comment: See the updated answer. Now the statement only updates telephone numbers that end in '.0'.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would be more comfortable with a more general solution, of taking everything before the period and adding a leading zero . . . if there is a period:

```
update t
    set tel = '0' || left(tel, position('.' in tel) - 1)
    where tel like '%.%';
```

The `where` checks that the change is made only on the rows that have the format suggested in the question.

If you want to insist that all numbers start with a zero, you might then want to do:

```
update t
    set tel = '0' || tel
    where tel not like '0%';
```

Comment: the first one will check the numbers end with '.0' and remove it then add 0 in front of this number ?

Comment: @MostafaMohamed . . . The first version checks any `tel` that has a period, and removes everything after the period.